# Can I create a free GitHub page with a custom domain?

Tags: github, github-pages

I was trying to create a GitHub page. The page name is taking after my user name: pritom008. It has become pritom008.github.io/pritom.github.io.

But I want to name it like pritom.github.io.
But when I tried I've got this message:

> You cannot use CNAMEs ending with github.io or github.com.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a custom github.io page named other than your account's name. If you want to have a GitHub page in the top of your domain, create a repository named **pritom008.github.io**.

Comment: If I follow this then the domain name becomes https://pritom008.github.io/pritom008.github.io